# Why there is no firing any error when redeclaring constants from incldued files in php?

Tags: php, constants

I'm using team project language files (programmatically created) for some project, where all teams have their own language terms, stored as constants in php files. And, of course, they share exact the same constant names. But, on one particular page I need to load more than one language file in the same page to display some values from language pack. However, there is no error displayed, nor constants are changed (which is obvious they can't). But why there is no error, at least a notice?

Sample loading file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

include "language/team_1.php";
include "language/team_2.php";

echo lang_dp_average_first_report;
```

where language/team_1.php looks like:

```
<?php
const lang_dp_and = 'and';
const lang_dp_average_first_report = 'First report average';
const lang_dp_breakdown_always = 'Always';
const lang_dp_breakdown_comments = 'Comments';
.....
```

and language/team_2.php looks like:

```
<?php
const lang_dp_and = 'and';
const lang_dp_average_first_report = 'First report median';
const lang_dp_breakdown_always = 'Always';
const lang_dp_breakdown_comments = 'Comments';
.....
```

it is perfectly clear that output will be value from the first included file, which is *First report average* but my question is why there is no error firing? I'm wondering if on clients' server that can cause issues due to (probable) different PHP configuration. I'm using MAMP Pro PHP 8.1.13

**Edit:**

my original file was loading composer's autoload file... which is somehow surpressing warning output's (not fatal errors)

```
<?php
include __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "vendor" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "autoload.php";
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
....
```

When I remove it, warnings are displayed. Probably some error handling within composer itself are handling warnings...

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. In particular, I'm wondering whether this requires multiple files at all. Also, how do you run this code? And where do you expect to find errors?

Comment: It should be a warning. I understand what you've posted is a simplified version. You must have some custom error handler or even some piece of code fiddling with error directives.

Comment: I do get an error in this situation: `Constant <...name...> already defined`.

Comment: I got too... however, my test was with included vendor/autoload.php and there is no error displayed. Without it, it is displaying warnings... can't figure it out why

Comment: Your warning settings are in `php.ini` (usually `/etc/php.ini`), See [error-reporting](https://php.net/error-reporting).

Comment: The `autoload.php` is missing from your question, so there's no way for me to replicate your situation. However, given your edit, perhaps you should switch on error reporting before you include the `autoload.php` file?

Comment: Tried both, again no errors. in php.ini file it says `display_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL`. When I remove vendor and erro reporting - still there is no error. I guess it is due to mine MAMP configration.

Comment: `autoload.php` is composer's generated file with trillion on files in the vendor folder so i cannot uplaod everything.